# Is there a way to have the topmost \ point to another drive?

Tags: windows, command-line, filesystems

In Windows, `\` points to `C:\`. Is there a way to have it point to another drive that isn't the system drive?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Other than this, if that was possible, a lot of programs would/could break.

Comment: I'm mostly just curious.

Comment: Please read this section about [asking](http://superuser.com/help/asking). Questions should be about actual problems you face, not hypothetical.

Comment: \ is not C:\, it's the current active drive's root. For example after changing the current directory to D:\etc then now \ points to D:\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while you cannot redirect a drive letter that is part of your system, you can add drive letters that can refer to any part of your system. e.g. you could make a drive X: that starts at C:\Users\Fred\MyDocuments, and can only go down from there, not any higher.

The command is `SUBST` and in my example, the command would be

```
SUBST X: C:\Users\Fred\MyDocuments
```

and when you have finished,

```
SUBST X: /D
```

from the help:

```
Associates a path with a drive letter.

SUBST [drive1: [drive2:]path]
SUBST drive1: /D

  drive1:        Specifies a virtual drive to which you want to assign a path.
  [drive2:]path  Specifies a physical drive and path you want to assign to
                 a virtual drive.
  /D             Deletes a substituted (virtual) drive.

Type SUBST with no parameters to display a list of current virtual drives.
```

Answer (score 6):

In Windows, simply the `\` path refers to *the root directory of the current partition*. If you only have a single partition mounted under a drive letter (which is often the case), that'll be it. If you have multiple partitions mounted under drive letters, say C: and D:, then if you are in a directory on the D: partition then `\` will refer to D:\.

Note that for example a DVD or a USB memory stick will have its own root directory, referred to as `\` while on that partition or drive, independent from the root directory of any built-in hard disk partitions.

This in contrast to Unix-like systems, where `/` refers to the root of the entire file system tree (since the concept of drive letters doesn't exist there; only mount points).